# swipe tabs by sliding in one fragment not using other fragments

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, swipe

I have a Fragment with TabLayout, and selecting by current tab it shows the selected month info, not hiding tabs bar and **don't using for that many fragments**, just updating the view. And now i need swipe tabs by finger sliding. I've searched and watch many examples which using ViewPager and many Fragments to describe each tab.

So how can i do this using **only one fragment** not other fragments?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code... You can easily create multiple instance of one Fragment in ViewPager, if that is what you're asking

Comment: so i need to create 30 instances min and i think it's not the right way

Comment: ViewPager doesn't create all the instances at once by default, just 3: current, previous and next...